# Sending and Receiving cXML PunchOutRequest in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sap-ariba, cxml-commercexml

I'm trying to integrate Ariba in my Rails application. Ariba uses cXML to punch out the data I need.

I found the gem https://github.com/officeluv/cxml-ruby so I can parse and create cXML request.

But finding difficult in punching out the request.

I tried to use an online simulator to punch out to my Rails application but I didn't receive any cXML request to my application.

What is the way to punch out cXML to a URL from Rails application and receive cXML from an external application?

Comment: Not really clear which direction you are trying to PunchOut as you mention "punching out **to**" your application and **from** your application.  Is your application representing the buyer or supplier?

Comment: I need to punch out from my application